# Optimal postgreSQL read-modify-write rows access

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Trying to modify some fields in all table records, using Npgsql data Provider for PostgreSQL.

Each record needs:

- to be read,
- some fields needs to be modified by a C# procedure
- and write back to table

Is there an object or mechanism that allow to point to each record to do this without multiple queries to perform the C# procedure call between the reading and writing of each record?

Comment: I can't really work out what you're asking. It sounds like you're expecting to have the db call into a c# app. Surely it's the other way round? Download a load of data to c#, edit it and send it back. It's how every database backed c# app in the world works - why are you looking to shake it up and do something different ?

Comment: Is a program in _**dotnet core**_ processing a very large amount of records, where some column fields needs to be replaced with a value resulting from a C# algorithm implementation.

Comment: And what is your specific objection to the typical pattern of `select * from table where I'd = 1; update table set column = value where I'd = 1`?

Comment: That pattern can't be used because you do not have the replacement value at query time, the value returned by the select has to be process by the C# procedure and then it's returned value is the one to update the field.

Comment: Er, yes.. C# provides "value" in `update table set column = value where ID = 1`. Perhaps I should have been more clear: *what is wrong with the typical pattern of `select a,b,c from table where ID = 1; <use c# to calculate new value of d from a,b,c>; update table set d = @new_d_from_csharp where ID = 1`*

Comment: Is slow because those tables are generated without indexing, so the select and the update query for each record sequentially accessed takes time.  In others database there are cursors in the language api (npsql) where you can access records directly get and modify the cursor data and commit the new values.  PostgreSQL have the _**refcursor**_ and searching in npsql documentation there is `NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor` buy is an enumerator and can't decipher if such functionality is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to update a value via an open cursor, to avoid an additional UPDATE, then that doesn't exist in PostgreSQL. On the other hand, I'm pretty sure (but not 100%) that on other databases it doesn't actually improve perf either, i.e. that an additional roundtrip for each update is required anyway. In other words, "updating a cursor" for results from a SELECT is probably API sugar rather than an actual optimization.

The most efficient way to accomplish this with Npgsql is probably to do a SELECT, buffer results in memory, iterate them to calculate the new values, and then issue a prepared batched update that updates the rows (i.e. a single command with several `UPDATE ...; UPDATE ...` statements). If the amount of rows is too large, this can be split into several batches, i.e. "load x rows, calculate, update those x rows; load next x rows...". You can use [PostgreSQL's cursor functionality](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) to each time load the next X rows, or simple issue new SELECTs and use LIMIT/OFFSET for paging (likely to have similar performance).

Comment: Thanks, but as the tables have no indexes the update is not an option because it needs the `WHERE` clause. We already solve the problem with the `refcursor` using part of what you suggest but without limit/offset (because the PostgreSQL documentation states that an ORDER has to be set or the LIMIT/OFFSET option can overlap and the issue tracking said that is not a bug). Instead, selecting all and using FETCH by Record, then call C# procedures and UPDATE using the cursor as WHERE. With this, is working, now performance has to be verify.

Comment: Uh, are you saying you're selecting many rows, doing a calculation on the client, and then updating the result - all because you have no index on your table? I may be misunderstanding, but that doesn't make much sense - selecting the relevant rows (SELECT ... WHERE ...) is very similar to simply updating them directly in the database (UPDATE ... WHERE ...) - both require an index to work efficiently.

Comment: Basically, if it's possible to do your changes in the database with a single `UPDATE ... WHERE ...`, I can't see any possible reason to do it in C# inside (definitely not perf).